# Tableau 9.2: Error while using Impala to connect to Cloudera CDH 5.5.1

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, tableau-api, impala

Setup:
- CDH 5.5.1, featuring Impala 2.3.0
- Tableau 9.2 with Cloudera ODBC Connector 2.5.30

I'm able to add the connection in Tableau to my cluster, and I'm able to list schema's and tables. However, as soon as I select a column in a worksheet, I get the following error:

> `[Cloudera][ImpalaODBC] (110) Error while executing a query in Impala: [42000]: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 1:7 Expression not in GROUP BY key '<column name>'`

Doing some research, I encountered old threads stating that ODBC version 2.5 doesn't support Tableau. Instead, I should use version 1.2. However, the latter is no longer on offer on the Cloudera website.

So, in short, the following questions aren't answered by google:

- Is there a way to get version 2.5.30 to work?
- Where can I download version 1.2?
- What are the drawbacks of using such an old version?
- Is it known when a new, working ODBC driver will be made available?

Comment: I'm assuming you cross-referenced the [Tableau drivers](https://www.tableau.com/support/drivers) and [Impala connectors](http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/downloads/connectors/impala/odbc/2-5-30.html)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean..
I tried different version of the Impala connector: 2.5.30, 2.5.20, 2.5.13.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cloudera Impala connect to Tableau Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42277800/cloudera-impala-connect-to-tableau-error)