# Cloudera Impala connect to Tableau Error

Tags: hadoop, tableau-api, cloudera, impala

I am working on using Tableau to connect to Cloudera Hadoop. I provide the server and port details and connect using Impala. I am able to successfully connect, select default Schema and choose the required table(s).

After this, when I drag and drop either a dimension or a measure to Rows/Columns on the `grid`, I get the below error:

```
[Cloudera][Hardy] (22) Error from ThriftHiveClient:
Query returned non-zero code: 10025, cause: FAILED:
SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 1:7 Expression not in GROUP BY key ''.
```

I saw several similar problems on the forum, but none of them got the solution Any help on this is very much appreciated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same problem before. The error occurs when Tableau try to run something like this:

```
   SELECT `table`.`param_1` AS `param_1`
   ,SUM(`table`.`param_2`) AS `sum_all` 
   FROM `db_name`.`table` 
   `table` GROUP BY 1
```

Since you can check the schema and tables. This **aggregation** may cause the problem.

I think you might need to check a few things:

1. Is your odbc driver version correct?  Cloudera ODBC driver 2.5.28 does 
   not support Tableau with Impala.
2. Did you choose the right port number or login type? Impala port
   number is 21000 and 21050. Hive is 10000.

For me the setup is **using port 21050 and choose Impala as Type with no authentication**. You can also choose Type HiveServer2 and using impala port number to login. But it didn't work on my case.

Hope that help.

Comment: Thanks. I always thought It was the odbc driver problem. Turns out it was a login setup problem. Now it works.